# Create non-animated spritesheet in JS

Tags: javascript, sprite-sheet

I'm struggling to get an image of a deck of small cards into spritesheet form using javascript.  I need to get them into an array so as to shuffle them.  Here's what I've got so far.  Only the canvas shows up light blue against a dark blue background.

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas#game-canvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left: 5%;
        background: lightblue;
        height: 281px;
        width: 500px;
      }
      body {
        background: darkblue;
      }    
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1_10_2_min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      function SpriteSheet(path, frameWidth, frameHeight) {

         this.image = new Image();
         this.frameHeight = frameHeight;
         this.frameWidth = frameWidth;


         // calculate the number of frames in a row after the image loads
         var self = this;
         this.image.onload = function() {
            self.framesPerRow = Math.floor(this.image.width / frameWidth);
         };

         this.image.src = path;

      }

      var spritesheet = new SpriteSheet('small_playing_cards.png', 54, 65);   
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you exactly want to do? PS: you're not drawing the image also, and it's missing the area x & y of where you want the frame.

Comment: Is this the full code? Are you intending to add methods to your `SpriteSheet` class to get individual sprites? You need something to map from cards to indexes in the sprite sheet, for one thing.

Answer (score 1):

That's an duplicated answer, anyway you can do it by creating one new canvas and drawing it on the main.

**PS**: that's not my costume code, so I'll do somethings I'd not do, as create variables, etc.

**1.** Create canvas element asigned as value from one variable;

```
var Area=document.createElement("canvas")
```

**2.** Set the frame size to this canvas;

```
Area.width=FrameWidth,
Area.height=FrameHeight
```

**3.** Draw the spritesheet in this canvas in the x/y (negative) where the frame you want is located;

```
var AContext=Area.getContext("2d");
AContext.drawImage(SpriteSheet,0-FrameX,0-FrameY);
```

**4.** Draw this canvas as image in the main canvas, but with x/y preference;

```
MainCanvas.drawImage(Area,PreferenceX,PreferenceY)
```

It's like these steps you can draw one frame from an spritesheet image. I'm not sure if it's that you want, I can't understand your question as well.